# Better way to achieve sprite image for list

Tags: html, css

I'm not happy with my code which uses a sprite image to show different images for each item in a list. The code can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/JBuE6/45/

Before it was possible to click anywhere along the width of the column and it would select the list item because I used display: block.

However, because my sprite requires:

```
width: 0px;
```

It means I have to click on the actual list text in order to select it. Removing the width: 0px from the class .nav li achieves the affect I want. Can anyone show me how to do this, with some clean efficient code.

Comment: Why would it require `width: 0px;`?

Comment: Otherwise it shows the entire sprite

Comment: Something like this? Pseudo elements, BOOM! http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/5Bv7p/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take advantadge of CSS pseudo-elements, like `::before`. You can do it in this way:

> http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/JBuE6/53/

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="url" id="user">User</a>
    </li>
    ...
```

CSS:

```
nav a {
  color: gray;
  display: block;
  line-height: 26x;
  width: 100%;
  }
nav li a::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  background:url('http://www.otlayi.com/web_images/content/free-doc-type-sprite-icons.jpg');
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  }
#user::before {
  background-position: -10px -6px;
  }
```

OLD ANSWER [alternative]:

I would change the padding left and the sprite to the `<a>`, so that you can click them also.

```
.nav li {
  }
.nav li a {
  color: gray;
  display: block;
  line-height: 26x;
  padding-left: 30px;
  background:url('http://www.otlayi.com/web_images/content/free-doc-type-sprite-icons.jpg');
  height: 20px;
  width: 0px;
  }
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/JBuE6/50/

Comment: This is good because I can click the image, but having the width: 0px still means that the display block is pretty much useless, removing it means I can't click all along the column, only on the text

Comment: I didn't like that so I just updated the answer. Also I didn't completely understand what you meant that you cannot click along the column, **updated**.

Answer (score 0):

You should be putting your images on the links, not the list. Use `display:block` and `padding-left:` to provide enough room. In general, put all non-positional styling on the `A`-tag, not the `LI`.

Other than that, you are doing it the right way.